# Debugging_Reversal Code of Two Words

Tags: python, debugging

```
def is_reverse(word1, word2):
     if len(word1) != len(word2):
          return False
     i = 0
     j = len(word2)-1

     while j > 0:
          if word1[i] != word2[j]:
               return False
          i = i+1
          j = j-1     
          return True

print(is_reverse('adverse', 'esrevda'))
```

I had made first code of mine which check two words reversely matching or not.

It looks working checked with my IDLE but want to ask experts any improvement would be needed.

Any Advice for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your indentation is incorrect,`return True` should be outside the while loop or just the first and last character need to match, e.g.:

```
>>> is_reverse('ab', 'ca')
True
```

I also assume you are doing this as an exercise because there are easier ways of doing this, e.g.:

```
def is_reverse(word1, word2):
    return word1 == word2[::-1]
```

Or if you really want to do it character by character:

```
def is_reverse(word1, word2):
    return all(c1 == c2 for c1, c2 in zip(word1, reversed(word2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just compare the two string.

```
def is_reverse(word1, word2): 
    return word1 == word2[::-1]
```